# .NET Windows Service says not responding even though I know it's running

Tags: .net, service

I have a .NET 2.0 windows service that I installed with installutil.exe. The function of the service is a Batch Processing service that traverses through an input file and processes each record and saves an output file. When I start the service in Windows Service, after 20 seconds it says the service isn't responding, so it stops the service, however I can see from the output file that the service is running fine. 
The exact message I receive is: Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I increased the Windows Service timeout with a registry hack, but it yields the same results (the only difference being it takes longer to receive the "not responding" message).

The OnStart method of my service looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{ 
     Producer producer = new Producer();
     ThreadStart st = new ThreadStart(producer.Produce); 
     workerThread = new Thread(st); 
     workerThread.Start();
}

static void Main()  
{
     System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
     ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new BatchService() }; 
     System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun); 
}
```

The Producer constructor:

```
public Producer()
{
     nMaxConcurentJobs =   int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxConcurentJobs"]); 
     if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[TIME_INTERVAL] != null)`  
     {
          sleepTime = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[TIME_INTERVAL]);
          sleepTime *= 1000;
     } 
}
```

Is there something I need to notify the windows service that its working?? Any help would be appreciated, I've been struggling with this for several days now!

Comment: Can you also post your `Main` and the `Producer` Constructor?

Comment: I don't see a culprit there, I suggest posting the constructor for your `BatchService` as @Steve Townsend suggested.  You've got some heavy lifting going on somewhere where it shouldn't be, just need to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure [OnStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) is geing called by having it make some kind of log output.

Make sure you are not doing a lot of work in your `ServiceBase`-derived class constructor, `OnStart` is the place to do heavy lifting.

If your startup logic is long-lasting you likely will have to call [RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx) to prevent the Service Control Manager (SCM) assuming your process died.  When you return from `OnStart` the SCM will mark your service as 'Running' in the Services GUI.

Design your app so that it can be run not as a service to make sure you have not deadlocks in that multi-threaded startup code.  Add appropriate diagnostic output to that logic to track its progress.

Comment: I have the log files, and it shows everything as working correctly. I posted my OnStart method, and as you can see, all it does is create a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any details about `Producer.Produce()` anywhere, but I do notice what seems to be a member called `sleepTime`.  Are you using `Thread.Sleep()`?  If so, have you tried using a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) or [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead?